# Sass map dynamic keys

Tags: sass, sass-maps

Is it possible to use variables as keys to define a map?

Example code

```
$types: (
        'INPUT': 1,
        'SELECT': 2,
        'BUTTON': 3,
);

$colors: (
        $types['INPUT'] : #f44336,
        $types['SELECT']: #2196f3,
        $types['BUTTON']: #9c27b0,
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it

```
@function type($key) {
  @return map-get($types, $key);
}

$colors: (
        type('INPUT'): #f44336,
        type('SELECT'): #2196f3,
        type('BUTTON'): #9c27b0,
}
```